# XODOutputOptions throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pdftron.SDF.ObjSet.Create()J

Tags: java, pdftron, jdk1.7

Executing following piece of code

```
import org.junit.Test;

import pdftron.PDF.Convert.XODOutputOptions;

public class TestPDFTron {

@Test
public void test() {
    new XODOutputOptions();
}

}
```

It throws following Exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pdftron.SDF.ObjSet.Create()J
at pdftron.SDF.ObjSet.Create(Native Method)
at pdftron.SDF.ObjSet.<init>(ObjSet.java:19)
at pdftron.PDF.Convert$XPSOutputCommonOptions.<init>(Convert.java:107)
at pdftron.PDF.Convert$XODOutputOptions.<init>(Convert.java:221)
at TestPDFTron.test(TestPDFTron.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Running on Windows 10 and JDK 7.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this happen if you call PDFNet.initialize() first?

Comment: Nop, it works. Thanks. Found also one other solution ...

Comment: Ryan add your comment as answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to call PDFNet.initialize() before any other PDFNet API methods.

Answer (score 2):

Posting here the solution I have found. Ryan gave a better answer and you should try his solution first ("call PDFNet.initialize() first").

Added

```
 -Djava.library.path=C:/Users/[myname]/workspaces/[anyotherfolders]/pdfnet
```

It is where I have the PDFNetC.dll and PDFNetC.lib.

Then in code added

```
System.loadLibrary("PDFNetC");
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, **initialize the PDFNet** library in a static block:

```java
    static {
        PDFNet.initialize();
    }
```

**Set `-Djava.library.path`** to the directory of PDFNet library files (.dll, .lib, .dylib).

In VS Code, in `launch.json`, I set the java library path to the PDFNet lib directory the following way:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "${file}",
      "vmArgs": ["-Djava.library.path=/Users/.../pdfnet"]
    }
  ]
```

On IntelliJ, click `Run`, `Edit Configurations...`, and then `VM Options` (under Configurations tab), add the value:

```
-Djava.library.path=/Users/.../pdfnet
```